# Merge array in array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

I currently have an array that holds an array of arrays:

```
    array(9) {
      ["enabled"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(14) "Enable/Disable"
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "checkbox"
        ["label"]=>
        string(25) "Enable"
        ["default"]=>
        string(3) "yes"
      }
    ["title"]=>
    array(5) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Title"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["description"]=>
    string(60) "This controls the title which the user sees during checkout."
    ["default"]=>
    string(18) "Retail Finance"
    ["desc_tip"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
```

This array is called `$test`. Now as you can see in this array there's an array called `"enabled"` at index 0, and an array called `"title"` at index 1. I'd like to splice another associative array between index 0 and 1. I've included this below:

```
'enable_finance_calculator' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Enable Calculator', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __( 'Enable Finance Calculator', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default' => 'yes'
        ),
```

Normally when doing this I'd use `array_splice()`, but this does not handle associative arrays. What is the best option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of involved but you can slice and merge:

```
$test = array_merge(
          array_slice($test, 0, $pos=array_search('enabled', array_keys($test), true)+1, true),
          $newarray,
          array_slice($test, $pos, NULL, true)
        );
```

- Search on the array keys to find the position and slice up to that
- Merge with the new array
- Merge with a slice from the position up to the end of the array

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, It's much less involved that the function I've been attempting to write to handle this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this (haven't tested it):

```
// Get first item off from index 0
$tempData = array_shift($data);

// Add new array $newData at index 0
array_unshift($data, $newData);

// Add old data again at index 0, rest of items should get an incremented index, so $newData is at 1 and ['title'] is at 2
array_unshift($data, $tempData);
```

Comment: This adds numeric indexes, check the result.